# How to determine no of parameters in a stored procedure in mysql from java

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

I want to build an application which determines no of parameters in a stored procedure . Let the no of parameters in a stored procedure is x . Then the application create x JLabel in the form .

I cant determine no of parameters in a stored procedure . How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a regular query using Java on `information_schema` database to obtain the number of parameters of a stored procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS 
WHERE 
    SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name' 
    AND SPECIFIC_NAME='your_procedure_name'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

You can see the structure of [`parameters` table here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/parameters-table.html).